# How do you send a null byte to a netcat server?

Tags: netcat

I have accessed a netcat server using the following command,

```
nc [IP] [PORT]
```

I need to send a null byte to the server to unlock a flag. How do I send a null byte.

I tried the following

- "\x00"
- 00000000

And many other variants.

Comment: Hi Mark, printf "\0" | nc  did not work . I found that you can send a null byte by hitting ctrl +shift +2. Im not sure why but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit the keys "Ctrl + Shift + 2" to send a null byte.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Where did you find this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf "\0" | nc ...
```